# How to Put Windows 10 directly to hibernation and power off (be able to show boot menu after next start)

Tags: windows-10, boot, sleep, hibernate

I have two disks with different systems in my PC (Win10 and Ubuntu). No GRUB-like dualboot. When I want to choose what system I'd like to run, I choose different boot device in (UEFI).

Now when I put my `Win10 Pro` into a sleep it uses a hybrid sleep (its hibernated into RAM, but it has a backup on a disk to keep state if power loss occures). So when I push power button it starts directly to Windows - I'm unable to invoke UEFI boot option menu.

I'd like to preserve this hybrid sleep, but also be able to directly hibernate Win to disk and then be able to boot Ubuntu and when work is finished, return to hibernated Windows.

My motherboard is `MSI B85-G41 PC Mate (MS-7850)`

It is somehow possible?

Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it's really easy.

No need to disable the hybrid sleep. There is setting which make "standard hibernation" available in shutdown menu.

Step by step:

1. Options
2. System
3. Power & sleep
4. Additional power settings
5. Choose what the power buttons do
6. Change settings what are currently unavailable
7. Tick checkbox with label: Hibernate (Show in Power menu) lower in this window.
   [Screenshot of the window](https://www.tenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/109998d1485973940t-change-default-action-power-button-windows-10-a-change_power_button_action-2.png?s=afe91a2b246bed79ca0241ff3326126f) (found on web I don't have EN version of the Win10 available here)

Now you can see a new option "Hibernate" in Shutdown menu (accessible from Start menu).

Possible problems:

I read that some mainboards are not put into power-off state when this option (hibernate) is used. And you cannot access BIOS/UEFI/Boot menu when you start your PC from hibernation. Luckily, it run as expected on my motherboard MSI B85-G41 PC Mate (MS-7850).